# Expected indented block in Python

Tags: python, runtime-error, block

I'm new to `Python`, and for the following part of the program:

```
while g != s and t < 8:
g = input("What is your guess? ")
if g < s:
    print ("Too low...")
    elif g > s:
        print ("Too high...")
        t = t + 1
```

I get the error:

`expected indented block`

Why is that? And, how can this issue be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: That line is not the problem in itself.  Please show us the surrounding code.  One or more of your lines needs to be indented.

Comment: @iCodez Thanks for your reply. I have added the surroundings

Answer (score 0):

python is based on whitespace ... you need to indent anything in a block (in other languages they use curly braces)

```
while g != s and t < 8: #indented 0 spaces
    #every thing below is part of this block so it needs to be indented
    g = input("What is your guess? ") #indented 4
    if g < s: #indented 4 spaces
        #this happens when its too low (one line indented)
        print ("Too low...") #indented 8 spaces
    elif g > s:  #indented 4 spaces
        #this happens when its too high(one line indented)
        print ("Too high...") #indented 8 spaces
    # this always happens for every iteration of the loop
    t = t + 1 #indented 4 spaces
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I'm new to `Python`, can you just kindly clarify that a bit. I couldn't notice the differences in your solution

Comment: I'm still having the same error. Is it just `new lines`? What does `indent` mean in Python? Is there an editor you recommend that does that automatically? Thanks

Comment: dont mix tabs and spaces ... use any editor that shows spaces/vs tabs ... indent means indent level (how many indents must line up) ...  I edited it to explicity say how many spaces its indented

Answer (score 0):

(as Joran Beasley says) The problem is likely to be that some of the lines are indented  using spaces, while others are indented with tabs.  There is also a possibility that some of the line have been indented with troll.

To be certain, turn 'show whitespace characters' on in your editor, so you can see which lines use tab characters to indent, and which lines use spaces for indentation.

Then, to fix the problem, pick one, either tabs or spaces, replace the other with it, and stick with the one you've chosen (preferably for life, or until you have to work with a developer with the opposing style).

Python doesn't mind which you use (tabs or spaces), just that you pick one and stick with  it for the duration of a source file.

```
this line is not indented
    this line is indented
```